# Selenium IDE datadrivenv0.2 issue with Firefox 20.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I have just updated my firefox to v 20.0. Whenever I open Selenium IDE in firefox , it show a popup error .

`Failed to load  user-extensions.js file=[PATH to file ...]datadriven_v0.2/datadriven.js lineNumber=37 error=ReferenceError:XML is not defined`.

The reported line in the file is sth like this :

```
XML.serialize = function(node) {
    if (typeof XMLSerializer != "undefined")
        return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(node) ;
    else if (node.xml) return node.xml;
    else throw "XML.serialize is not supported or can't serialize " + node;
}
```

I do not know any thing specific to selenium IDE ,if XML is part of Selenium IDE or firefox . However, it seems latest updates to Firefox has sth to do.

I ll appreciate if someone help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by declaring the XML-Object in datadriven.js before it is called.

```
var XML = {};
XML.serialize = function(node) {
    if (typeof XMLSerializer != "undefined")
        return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(node) ;
    else if (node.xml) return node.xml;
    else throw "XML.serialize is not supported or can't serialize " + node;
}
```

I don't know if this has any side effects, but for me it works.

Comment: Yes, this is a suitable workaround for newer versions of Firefox, which has removed the XML object. Also, newer versions of SelBlocks no longer depend on the XML object.

Answer (score 1):

Sven's idea worked perfectly for me.  I added the command

var XML = {};

to the beginning of my user-extensions.js file, closed FF and Selenium, and restarted them.  They've been working perfectly since then.  I'm up to FF v21.0 with no problems.

Thanks Sven!

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this for anyone using sel-blocks; the above solutions don't seem to work, since sel-blocks is an add-on and not a user-extension. However, there is still a solution. I added the line suggested above:

var XML = {};

to this file instead:

xmlextras.js

This file can be found in (selenium extension folder)/chrome/content/selenium-core/scripts

If you aren't sure how to get to your selenium extension folder, roughly here is how:

C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles(your firefox profile)\extensions{a6fd85ed-e919-4a43-a5af-8da18bda539f}

I apologize if I'm not using the correct format for posting an answer or anything, but I just want to make sure that anyone searching for the answer I was looking for is able to find something.

Answer (score -1):

From checking the Selenium website, the latest version of SIDE only supports up to Firefox version 17.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes

Comment: It was working under 19 perfectly it has sth to do with latest version of firefox or might be the datadriven selenium addon needs update.